# Adtonomy (jwplayer) link open in same tab

Tags: xml, flash, jwplayer

I set the adtonomy in jwplayer and it works good, but I want that, when I click on it then the adv url opens in same tab. Because (I think default), it opens in new tab at now.

How to?

Thanks.

Comment: It should open in a new window/tab by default (_blank). Do you have a link to where you are running this?

Comment: www.gazdasagtv.hu there are a some pre-roll spots.

Comment: The preroll opens in a new window (_blank), for me.

Comment: Yes, and I want that it not be so. I want that it opens same tab so _self.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not configurable. It is hard coded into the source as _blank.